# Ruby Blocks (Yield)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm just getting started with Ruby, I'm pretty a ways into my course at Bloc but now I am stuck on an exercise pertaining to yield and blocks(Which I am finding to be the hardest concept to grasp so far when it comes to learning ruby).

Here are the required specs in plain formatted text:

- Define a new_map method
- It should take an array as an argument and return a new array modified according to the instructions passed in as a block.
- You may not use the .map or .map! methods
- However, Feel free to use each within the method
- You'll want to store the return value from each block invocation in a new array
- It should map any object

---

Here are the RSpecs that need to be met:

```
describe "new_map" do
  it "should not call map or map!" do
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    a.stub(:map) { '' }
    a.stub(:map!) { '' }

    expect( new_map(a) { |i| i + 1 } ).to eq([2, 3, 4])
  end

  it "should map any object" do
    a = [1, "two", :three]
    expect( new_map(a) { |i| i.class } ).to eq([Fixnum, String, Symbol])
  end
end
```

---

Here is the original def method they gave me to start with:

```
def new_map(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each do |item|
    # invoke the block, and add its return value to the new array
  end
end
```

---

Then here is my current code(Updated):

```
def new_map(a)
  new_array = []
  a.each do |item|
    # invoke the block, and add its return value to the new array.
    yield(item, new_array)
  end
end

a = [2, 3, 4]

new_map(a) do |i, e|
  e << i
end
```

---

Finally when I submit the current code I just listed, I receive the following errors (Updated):

> new_map should not call map or map! (INCOMPLETE)

```
    expected: [2, 3, 4]
     got: [1, 2, 3]

(compared using ==)
exercise_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

---

> new_map should map any object (INCOMPLETE)

```
expected: [Fixnum, String, Symbol]
     got: [1, "two", :three]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Just as it says - when you call `new_map(a)`, `a` is undefined. Set it to an initial value, such as an array of numbers before calling new_map.

Comment: @ChrisHeald didn't work, I set `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` between the method definition and the method call , The program executes now but I'm getting `expected: [2, 3, 4]
     got: [] `

Comment: Also, maybe consider the comment text more fully. Step 1) Execute the block. Step 2) Add its value to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're failing to realise is that yield can return a value. The last executed statement in a block is the returned value.

So you can take the results from each yield call and add it to your resulting array.

Then, have the resulting array as your return value from your `new_map` method.

```
def new_map(a)
  new_array = []
  a.each do |item|
    # invoke the block, and add its return value to the new array.
    new_array << yield(item)
  end
  new_array
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def new_map(a)
  new_array = []
  a.each do |item|
    # # invoke the block, and add its return value to the new array.
    puts yield(item) # just experimenting
  end
end

new_map(a) { |i| i + 1 }
```

This `yield` thingy just takes each element from the array, and runs it through the block. This experimental code just prints the results; these should be collected in an array. Not hard:

```
def new_map(a)
  new_array = []
  a.each do |item|
    new_array = []
    # invoke the block, and add its return value to the new array.
    new_array << yield(item)
  end
end
```

This will not pass all tests, but the last step should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

`new_array` is created in the definition `new_map`, which is a different "lexical scope" than the block you write when you call `new_map`. Basically, code in the `new_map` method can see `new_array`, but code in your block cannot. One way to fix this problem might be by looking at the `Enumerable` methods `inject` or `each_with_object` that could work in place of `each` in your `new_map` method.